# UITextChecker and "Spell Checking"

Tags: iphone, uitextinput

I've successfully implemented UITextChecker in my custom view conforming to UITextInput to present users with the suggestions. I'd like to disable this feature based on the state of "Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Check Spelling" settings option. How do I go about doing this without creating the very same duplicate option in my app's settings?

I can't seem to find any way to access this access settings option nor did I find anything at the Apple's docs.

Any help would be appreciated.